# How to store base64 pdf ina variable using html2pdf?

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

Got a curious situation where if I run `google.script.run.savePdf(file, fileName)` within `.then()`, it just doesn't get run when I check the logs in the server-side.
If I run it after `html2pdf....then()`, the file gets saved, but it's empty. So, I thought I'd store it in a variable and pass it to the server side after, but I get an error, as the object returned seems to be illegal.

```
function savefile() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pgBody");
  var poNumber = document.getElementById('fabricPo').value;
  var supplier = document.getElementById('selectSupplier').value;
  let fileName = supplier + " - " + poNumber + ".pdf";
  var opt = {
    margin: [2, 5, 2, 5], //top, left, bottom, right
    filename: fileName,
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98,
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2,
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "mm",
      orientation: "landscape",
    },
  };
     let file = ''
 html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .outputPdf()
    .then(function (p) {
      file += btoa(p);
    });
    google.script.run.savePdf(file, fileName);
    window.print();
    google.script.host.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the arrow function.

```
 html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .outputPdf()
    .then((p) => {
      file += btoa(p);
    });
    google.script.run.savePdf(file, fileName);
    window.print();
    google.script.host.close();
```

Or use `await` syntax.

```
async function savefile() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pgBody");
  var poNumber = document.getElementById('fabricPo').value;
  var supplier = document.getElementById('selectSupplier').value;
  let fileName = supplier + " - " + poNumber + ".pdf";
  var opt = {
    margin: [2, 5, 2, 5], //top, left, bottom, right
    filename: fileName,
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98,
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2,
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "mm",
      orientation: "landscape",
    },
  };
  let file = ''
  const p = await html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .outputPdf()

    file += btoa(p);
    google.script.run.savePdf(file, fileName);
    window.print();
    google.script.host.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I keep getting the same result. Logged ```file``` and that is empty

Comment: @onit Did you check the value of `btoa(p)`?

Comment: This piece doesn't even seem to run. I've logged btoa(), but it doesn't even show as empty or ```null``` ```html2pdf()
   .set(opt)
   .from(element)
   .outputPdf()
   .then(function(p) {
     console.log('Base 64' + btoa(p))
     pdfFile += btoa(p);
   });```  Thanks for asking

Comment: @onit Try to use `catch` if you are using `then`, or if you are using `await` try to surround the code in `try/catch` block and try to console the `error`, I suspect that it may the `html2pdf` fire an error and stop executing.

Comment: No apparent error. I'll keep investigating. Thank you